# How can I make a table view with different height of cell?

Tags: ios, swift

For Example

I need a table with 3 sections and each section has only one cell.

then I want the cell in section one has height of 90 and in other section has height of 150

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use tableView `heightForRowAtIndexPath` Delegate method to increase cell height.

try this code

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGFloat {
         if (indexPath.section==0) {
            return 90 // your height
        }
        else if (indexPath.section==1) {
            return 150 // your height
        }
        else {
            return 90 // third section cell height
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Refer to apple document [Apple document Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:)

[image]

> Discussion
>   The method allows the delegate to specify rows with varying heights. If this method is implemented, the value it returns overrides the value specified for the rowHeight property of UITableView for the given row.

Answer (score -1):

Refer below code-

```
    -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{if (indexPath.section == 0) {
           return 90;
    }}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using static cells and storyboard then you can directly set height from storyboard.

Else you can use method heightForRowAtIndexPath and use if or switch statement to set height for a particular cell.